# power of ten modulo prime

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, congruences

In a mathematical quiz (that I solved by computational means), I came across the problem of finding powers k of ten with a given congruence to a given prime number, 
$$10^k \equiv q \text{ mod } (p)$$
as eg
$$10^k \equiv 46 \text{ mod } (47)$$
and I wonder if there is a generic approach to this problem.

Comment: Just for the record $\min k=23$ Other $k$ values $23,69,115,161,207,253,299,345,391,437,483,529,575,621,667,713,759,805,851,897,943,989,\ldots$ In general $k=23 (2 n-1)\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. Quite interesting $10^k \equiv 96 \text{ mod } (97)$ has a similar set of solutions $k=48 (2 n-1)\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. But this is not general  for primes or composites integers. For the moment results seem quite random. I mean that they exist for $47$ and $97$  but not for 37. Doesn't depend on $4n+1$ or $4n+3$ primes. It's intriguing, anyway...

Comment: @raffaele: if 10 is a primitive root mod  p there are solutions, 10 is no primitive root mod 37.

Comment: @Raffaele: thank you for the example. Is there any generic result for 23=(47-2)/2 to be the solution or any link with [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)? For instance, when using 89 as the basis, 10⁴⁴≡1 (89) and 10²²≡-1 (89)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) poblem. In your case there is another simple solution: You have $46 \equiv -1 \bmod {47}$. If $10$ would be a primitive root, you would have $10^{23} \equiv -1 \bmod {10},$  and $k=23$ is indeed a solution. For a general prime $p$ you would check $10^{(p-1)/2}.$

If you change your problem to $10^k \equiv 45 \bmod {47}$ a few iterations of 
[Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) give $k=7$.

Comment: Thanks for the $(p-1)/2$ solution, it works indeed. I had not thought of (-1)^2=1...!